# Hibernate annotations using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am using hibernate annotations in my application. But I am getting one problem.

### class A

```
@Entity
@Table(name = DBConstants.T_A )
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A {

   //Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = A_SEQ)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = A_SEQ, sequenceName=SeqA_SEQ)
    private long id;

   ....
}
```

### class B

```
//Entity
@Table(name = "T_B")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "a_id")
public class B extends A{

   String a;
 .....
}
```

### class C

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_C")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "a_id")
public class C extends B
{
...
}
```

Initially, I am saving the `class A`.
After some time, while saving `class C`, I set Class A `id` which was **saved already**. While trying to save the class C, it creates a new `class A` object and sets that newly created object value to class C object. I needed the `class C` object with `class A` object id which is created at first.

I don't understand why a new object of `class A` is created again. Can anyone please answer to my question what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want C to have the same id as an object A that already exists, this is not really entity inheritance.

You basically want a reference to an existing object and you should be using a `@OneToOne` relationship to map this.